Let $z$ be an upper bound for $A \subset \Re$ such that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $x \in A$ such that $x > z − \epsilon$. Then $z = \sup A$.
Let $z$ be an upper bound for $A \subset \Re$ such that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $x \in A$ such that $x > z − \epsilon$. Then $z = \sup A$. How to prove this statement?
My attempt is to prove the statement by contradiction. Namely by assuming that $z \neq \sup A$ and finding that the required properties for $z$ are no longer met.
I assume $z \neq \sup A$, then either $z < \sup A$ or $z > \sup A$. If $z < \sup A$ then $z$ is no longer an upper bound, a contradiction. And so $z \geq \sup A$. Now let $z > \sup A$. Then we can find an $\epsilon < z - \sup A$ so that $z - \epsilon > \sup A$ which means there is no $x \in A$ such that $x > z - \epsilon$ since $z - \epsilon$ is greater than $\sup A$, a contradiction. And so $z \geq \sup A$ and $z \ngtr \sup A$ which means $z = \sup A$. Which concludes the proof.
I feel I should add that this is not part of any course I'm taking. Also I found an equivalent question here, however I only understand the first part of the proof given by OP.

Isn't what you are proving the definition of upper bound?

The question is excellent and the proof is correct. You could shorten it a bit though.

@rushusuixing We need to prove the equivalence of this definition in the question with the definition that " $z$ is an upper bound and if $w$ is another upper bound then $z\leq w$"..

@Medo If you would provide the shorter proof as an answer I'll accept it.

Let $z$ be an upper bound for $A \subset \Re$ such that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $x \in A$ such that $x > z - \epsilon$. We prove $z = \sup A$ by contradiction. Let $z \neq \sup A$, then $z < \sup A$ or $z > \sup A$. If $z < \sup A$ then $z$ is not an upper bound, a contradiction. Therefore $z \geq \sup A$. If $z > \sup A$ then there exists an $\epsilon < z - \sup A$ and therefore $z - \epsilon > \sup A$ meaning there is no $x \in A$ such that $x > z - \epsilon$, a contradiction. And so $z \ngtr \sup A$, therefore $z = \sup A$.
